# require rubygems in SketchUp

Tags: ruby, plugins, sketchup

I have been trying to find out searching online how to require rubygems in SketchUp, but have been unable to find out specifically how.

Below is my plugin in `C:\Program Files\Google\Google SketchUp 8\Plugins\gems.rb`:

```
$: << 'C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8'
$: << 'C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i386-msvcrt'
$: << 'C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/site_ruby'
$: << 'C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8'
$: << 'C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32'
$: << '.'
require 'rubygems'
```

And I got the following error:

```
Error: #<LoadError: C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32/thread.so: 127: The specified procedure could not be found.   - C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32/thread.so>
(eval):14
C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/thread.rb:5
C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:11:in `require'
C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:11
(eval):14:in `require'
(eval):14
```

However, thread.so is exactly in `C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32`:

```
C:\Ruby186\lib\ruby\1.8\i386-mingw32>ls
Win32API.so    digest.so      fcntl.so   openssl.so   sdbm.so      version.h
bigdecimal.so  dl.h           gdbm.so    racc         socket.so    win32
config.h       dl.so          iconv.so   rbconfig.rb  st.h         win32ole.so
curses.so      dlconfig.h     intern.h   re.h         stringio.so  zlib.so
dbm.so         dln.h          io         regex.h      strscan.so
defines.h      enumerator.so  missing.h  ruby.h       syck.so
digest         env.h          nkf.so     rubyio.h     thread.so
digest.h       etc.so         node.h     rubysig.h    util.h
```

Trying to test in SketchUp Ruby Panel:

```
> require 'bigdecimal'
true
> require 'curses'
true
> require 'dbm'
true
> require 'digest'
true
> require 'digest/md5'
Error: #<LoadError: C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32/digest/md5.so: 126: The specified procedure could not be found.   - C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32/digest/md5.so>
(eval):14
(eval):14
> require 'digest\md5'
Error: #<LoadError: C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32/digest\md5.so: 126: The specified procedure could not be found.   - C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32/digest\md5.so>
(eval):14
(eval):14
> require 'digest/sha1'
Error: #<LoadError: C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32/digest/sha1.so: 126: The specified procedure could not be found.   - C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32/digest/sha1.so>
(eval):14
(eval):14
> require 'digest\sha1'
Error: #<LoadError: C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32/digest\sha1.so: 126: The specified procedure could not be found.   - C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32/digest\sha1.so>
(eval):14
(eval):14
> require 'digest\sha2'
true
> require 'digest/sha2'
true
```

## 2 Questions

1. Why some of files in `C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32` can be required correctly, while some can't and prompt LoadError?
2. Why the last two lines return both `true`? Does is has something to do with the loading problem?

## Environment

- Windows 7
- Ruby 1.8.6
- SketchUp 8.0.14346

PS. [Another same issue here](http://www.smustard.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=96)